# Как создать фрагмент подобный ленте инстаграма?

Tags: java, android, instagram

Посоветовали с помощью RecyclerView, почитал об этом, но пока выходит только список из картинок подгружать. Как сделать в layout под каждой картинкой нижнее меню с "лайк, комментарий, отправить"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Добрый день   во-первых вам надо создать разметку Xml тоесть создаете
  1 layout в
     него пихаете все что вам нужно кнопки иконки тд тп

  во вторых
     создаете    ListView(рекомендую RecyclerView у него уже вы обязаны
     реализовать    pattern ViewHolder)

  в третьих создаете кастомный адаптер
     наследуясь от какого    либа адаптера допустим BaseAdapter передаете
     ему через infalte вашу    рамзметку.

  Вот и всё

Так же вот вам ссылка на некотору. бизнесс логику может понадобится

### [делаем свой иснтаграмм](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eg2Xaq4Qoc)